# Get all substrings inside parentheses in Golang regexp

Tags: regex, go

I want to get all the substrings inside all parentheses in go using Regex.

As an example for the string "foo(bar)foo(baz)golang", i want "bar" and "baz"

in python i can do `re.findall("(?<=\()[^)]+(?=\))", "foo(bar)foo(baz)golang")`

How to do it in go?

Comment: Note that in Python you can use `re.findall(r"\(([^)]+)\)", "foo(bar)foo(baz)golang")` to get the same results. You do not have to use lookarounds with `re.findall`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`go`'s `regexp` package does not support zero width lookarounds. You can leverage captured grouping with the `regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch()` function:

```
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    str := "foo(bar)foo(baz)golang"
    rex := regexp.MustCompile(`\(([^)]+)\)`)
    out := rex.FindAllStringSubmatch(str, -1)

    for _, i := range out {
        fmt.Println(i[1])
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
bar
baz
```

---

The Regex `\(([^)]+)\)`:

- `\(` matches literal `(`
- `([^)]+)` matches substring upto next `)` and put the match in a captured group, here you can use non-greeedy match `.*?\)` too
- `\)` matches literal `)`

---

[Go playground demo](https://play.golang.org/p/YqcnWiBapg)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\((.*?)\)
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/KlIUre/1)

Code Sample:

```
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`\((.*?)\)`)
    var str = `foo(bar)foo(baz)golang`

    mt:= re.FindAllStringSubmatch(str, -1)

    for _, i := range mt {
        fmt.Println(i[1])
    }
}
```

[Run the go code here](http://ideone.com/JyP5g2)