# FindAllStringSubmatch in long string

Tags: regex, go

I have long search string (cutout):

```
s := `<option value='1'>Name A</option><option value='2'>Name B</option><option value='3'>Name C</option><option value='4'>Name D</option><option value='5'>Name E</option><option value='6'>Name F</option><option value='7'>Name G</option>`
```

And I want to search for the value and the name:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`ue='([0-9]+)'\>(.+)\</o`)
arr := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(s, -1)
```

Instead of returning the value I need, the function returns

```
[[ue='1'>Name A</option><option value='2'>Name B</option><option value='3'>Name C</option><option value='4'>Name D</option><option value='5'>Name E</option><option value='6'>Name F</option><option value='7'>Name G</o 1 Name A</option><option value='2'>Name B</option><option value='3'>Name C</option><option value='4'>Name D</option><option value='5'>Name E</option><option value='6'>Name F</option><option value='7'>Name G]]
```

Please help so it returns more like

```
[[ue='1'>Name A</o 1 Name A][ue='2'>Name B</o 2 Name B][... etc
```

I checked the culprit is around (.+), but it always failed to return the expected one, its expanded to the end of the string.

Comment: You're wanted output is really strange. Are you sure you wrote it right?

Comment: Yes. It is form of `[[{full string match} {substring1} {substring2}]]`

Comment: Please check if help you: https://play.golang.org/p/z7hzIQjvNID

Answer (score -1):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586313/get-all-substrings-inside-parentheses-in-golang-regexp) is different, but the answer is fit to my problem.

I replace the `(.+)` with `([^\<]+)` so the final line

```
 re := regexp.MustCompile(`ue='([0-9]+)'\>([^\<]+)\<`)
```